# Packages canceling each other? (Font-Changing problems)

Tags: fonts, preamble

I'm fairly new to Latex, and recently I started to compile my files with XeLaTeX (because I learned that would be helpful since sometimes I need to type some texts in Japanese), but recently I caught myself with a huge mess in my preamble and, for some reason, I am not being able to change fonts (I like to use the Palatino for text and the eulervm for the mathematics).

I like to have the packages loaded there because I never am sure of what direction my text will end up going to and I'd probably end up having to "find" them all again if I came across the need for something specific. Here's a simple test I made:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{zxjatype}
%\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,multicol,commath,graphpap,tabularx,tabulary,ragged2e}
%\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{arcs,tikz,pstricks,gensymb,bigints,wasysym,paralist,enumitem,cancel,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{microtype,siunitx,array,multirow,float,comment,icomma}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false] {caption} % usar labelfont={bf, footnotesize} para cabeçalhos em negrito e em outro tamanho de fonte.
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

%\usepackage[math]{kurier}


\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
%Para fazer números em círculos
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\textrm{sen}}

\begin{document}

Nossa 1ª definição: Se $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ é derivável em $x_0$, então $f$ é contínua em $x_0$.

\end{document}
```

This output will print in the regular CM font, which is clearly not what I want (the math font is euler, as I wanted, though). Notice the need for the character "ª", I'm pointing that out because sometimes, while tempering with the first lines of the preamble I manage to get the font to palatino, but the character "ª" and "º" are both replaced by characters like "z" but with the "^" hat.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex! if using xetex you need to use Unicode encoded fonts not classic 8-bit (T1) encoded fonts, use the `fontspec` package instead. similarly don't load 8-bit font packages (palatino, euler)

Comment: unrelated to xetex but I wouldn't load commath

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Out of curiosity, is it possible to use `fontspec` to set the text font into Computer Modern Sans? I'm looking for some kind of font list to use.

Comment: well latin modern sans, yes just as in classic tex `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}` after `\usepackage{fontspec}`

Comment: loading all those packages massively slows down document processing (the file access is often slower than actual processing these days)  how many documents do you really have that use pstricks and tikz at the same time. Why not add the \usepackage lines but comment them out, if you just want to remind yourself for future use. If you do load them use them! so not `\providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\textrm{sen}}` (which is the wrong spacing, and wrong size if used in subscripts) use `\DeclareMathOperator\sin{sen}`

Comment: I spent the last 47 minutes organizing the preamble I had, now I separated each package into it's own line and added comments with short explainations as to what they do and what they require. I commented it all out so I get to use only what necessary. The previous preamble was the result of me searching in forums and adding in any packages that I saw.

Comment: Also: `\DeclareMathOperator\sin{sen}` gave me an error.

Comment: sorry:-) `\let\sin\relax\DeclareMathOperator\sin{sen}`